# how to dynamically add array in object in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some md-chips in my HTML:-

```
<label>Label 1</label>
    <md-chips ng-model="first.set.value.arr1" placeholder="Hit enter after every value ">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>

<label>Label 2</label>
    <md-chips ng-model="first.set.value.arr2" placeholder="Hit enter after every value ">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>

<label>Label 3</label>
    <md-chips ng-model="first.set.value.arr3" placeholder="Hit enter after every value ">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{$chip}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
```

...... and many more.

Each of these chips value should be pushed in array. I want to create the array dynamically looping through each object.And pushed the value in API.

My directive Code:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('abc', abc);

    abc.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', 'ApiServices'];

    function abc($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {

            },
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.first = {};

                scope.save = function(){
                    ApiServices.add(scope.newRole).then(function (response){
                        console.log(response.data); 
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }); 
                };

            },
            templateUrl: 'js/folder/directives/myPage.html'
        };
    }

})();
```

How should I create the array dynamically and if I need to add more chips later it should create the array for the same.

Comment: just take object first it will contain  all your chips, if you want to add more chips in future, then also you can add those in this object. No need to create another array and push data into that. Just get your $scope.first object it will contain all details of your chips, If you are looking for a dynamic chip adding in Ui then go for ng-repeat

Comment: did you try ng-repeat? then try to push?.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, I can't use ng-repeat nor I can take only first object. In ng-model 'first.set' is fixed and 'value.arr1' keeps changing for every new chip. So I need to add object and array both dynamically.

Comment: let it change no issues. If the values are dynamic then instead of replacing the content of your object first , just push the new contents to it. Then object first will contain all the data. You UI also will reflects with dynamic data if you use ng-repeat as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `ng-repeat` and put a single chip in a wrapper. Here is an example:
In `HTML` :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in chips">
    <label>{{item.label}}</label>
    <md-chips ng-model="{{item.value}}" placeholder="Hit enter after every value ">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{item.chip}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
</div>
```

and in your controller use an array like:

```
var $scope.chips = [{'label': 'Label1', 'value': 1, 'chip': 'Chip 1'}, {'label': 'Label2', 'value': 2, 'chip': 'Chip 2'}];
```

Whenever you want to add a chip object, just push it into the array:

```
$scope.chips.push({'label': 'Label3', 'value': 3, 'chip': 'Chip 3'});
```